How to restudy functional analysis
I am re-studying functional analysis to prepare for my next year's PDE courses, I've taken it this year but I feel like I am not very good at it. May I ask what is the study routine/strategy for someone restudying it?
Usually, when I begin studying something as a beginner, I follow this routine: "intuition $\rightarrow$ exercise $\rightarrow$ see which topic I am not good at and focus". But I am not sure if that's the same procedure to follow as an intermediate learner.
I guess my question is both of the nature of "studying functional analysis" and "restudying a general topic or subject".
New:
Thanks for all your suggestions! By the way, I saw that Cambridge suggests Béla Bollobás' Linear Analysis, but I find it difficult to understand (a bit terse compared to the other books), am I stupid or what? If a book seems too hard should I switch, or press on try to understand?

What I do is writing a script with really detailed proofs to grasp every step and get a good understanding of the topics. Then I do exercises to test my knowledge and after every exercise I include them in my Script as examples or Corollaries. That takes a long time but is really fun imo. Other possibilities are just studying with books ig.

I'd go through a book that has exercises and solutions and just try to solve every exercise that is related to the topics you want to study. For PDEs, Alt - Linear Functional Analysis is quite nice, because it has solutions and focuses on applications.

I really liked Brezis book on functional analysis. There is a plethora of exercises and you can find the solutions online.

@EvangelopoulosFoivos May I ask is the title "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations"?

Yeap, that's it!

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thanks a lot! By the way, if you encounter a textbook which you find difficult, should you change or press on to understand? I was using Bollobás' Linear Analysis and finding it too terse for me.

I would recommend finding something that suits your style. There is a plethora of books anyways

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Thanks a lot!
